# How to retrieve one row of data with MySQL in chunks

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

Our legacy system used to put large amount of binary data directly in database, like (I know it's bad design, but compatibility comes first):

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_table (
  id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  data longblob
);
```

While running, the system should retrieve one row of data from the database (using `MySQL-python`) and do some stuff with the data:

```py
# simplified, removed some error-handling logic
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='xxx', port='xxx', user='xxx', passwd='xxx', db='xxx')
with connection.cursor(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:
    cursor.execute('SELECT data FROM data_table WHERE id = %s', (123,))
    data = cursor.fetchall()[0]['data']
    # do some stuff with the data
```

The problem comes: data **in a single row** may be quite large (>1GB), while the system runs in a container with memory limit of 1GB, so even fetching a single row results in an OOM (Out Of Memory) error and the system crashes.

Is there a way to stream data in one row directly to external storage, or to retrieve data in chunks to avoid OOM error? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** We're using MySQL 5.7 but upgrading MySQL version may also be acceptable if it's helpful for solving this problem.

Comment: What is precise MySQL version?

Comment: @Akina I think we're using MySQL 5.7; but will upgrading MySQL version help?

Comment: In 5.7 you may try to use stored procedure which divides long value in a row to a lot of rows with chunks, then fetch rows one-by-one (i.e. fetchOne in cycle, not all with fetchAll) and concatenate back on the client side. In 8+ you may use CTE for these purposes.